# Alternatives for pandas apply with slice

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, slice, apply

I have a `df` with columns `open, high, low, close` representing stock prices. I check for liquidity if `high != low`, and I do it for each row considering all previous rows. `apply` function works correct, but a little bit slow. Is there an option to make it faster?

```
df['liquid'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df.loc[:x.name, 'high'] != df.loc[:x.name, 'low']).all(), axis=1)
```

Comment: use a def instead of lambda

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `np.where` which made it 42 times faster finally

```
cum_len = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
cond = (df['high'] != df['low']).cumsum() == cum_len
df['liquid'] = np.where(cond, True, False)
```